# Coordinate Chart vs Parametrization

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Take a torus as an example: One could define the points that lie on it using a two-dimensional parametrization. Take the "equation" of a torus:

$$
x = [R_1 + R_2 \cos(v)] \cos(u) \\
y = [R_1 + R_2 \cos(v)] \sin(u) \\
z = R_2 \sin(v)
$$

How is this different from coordinate charts, for which I believe you would need 2 (or 4 if they are to be simply connected)? Is the only distinction between them that coordinate charts need to be open sets? If so, practically, what is the difference between the two ways to map points from a manifold to $\mathbb{R}^n$? (I appreciate that for a sphere there is the issue of the poles and division by zero, is this really the only reason?)

The only other distinction could be that the coordinate charts are invertible, but couldn't you just restrict the domain for this to work?

Comment: The definition of a manifold does not suppose that the manifold is embedded in a larger ${\mathbb R}^n$ space. That's one of the reasons why coordinate charts are necessary. Another question is the invertibility of the change of coordinates.

Comment: A coordinate chart is indeed a parameterization of an open subset of a manifold.